# troubleshooting OpenVPN not connecting to the server

Tags: windows, openvpn

I've installed OpenVPN GUI for Windows, created and put config file to the appropriate folder. When I'm pressing "Connect", it shows a progress window (without any messages) and after a few seconds - "can't connect to the server" error. I'm trying to find a log file, but there isn't any.
Any ideas what can I do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary to run the program as Admin, but the app's shortcut doesn't enforce that.